# Disable hostname verification in JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: ssl, jboss, cxf, hostname

I'd like to set my dev environment in order to avoid the hostname verification in https connection: I imported successfully che certificate in cacerts but I'm getting this error

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.
```

I tried to add this line to standalone.xml (inside system-properties)

```
<property name="org.jboss.security.ignoreHttpsHost" value="true"/>
```

This system property is correctly set in JVM (saw by System.getProperty) but I'm still getting the above exception: what is the way to avoid the hostname verification without edit the application code?

I don't want to use disableCNCheck because it would be a change at level code.

Comment: The `org.jboss.security.ignoreHttpsHost` property doesn't do what you want it to, read [this paragraph](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/WebServices_Guide/en-US/html/chap_JBossWS-Securetransport.html#JBossWS-Securetransport_Client_side) of the JBossWS-Securetransport documentation. Your problem is related to the hostname you are connecting to, ie `localhost:8080` not matching whatever's in the CN-field of the certificate, ie `mysite.com`. A bit more information would be good; hostname you're trying to connect to and the CN-field of the certificate

Comment: The certificate is issued to https://something:443, through a SSH tunnel I reach this endpoint using https://localhost:9443. Using hosts file I can translate something as localhost, unfortunately I can't use 443 port.

Comment: Hosts file would be my number one suggestion, but seeing as you can't use that my next suggestion would be using something like nginx and redirecting localhost:9443 to something:443